# Automatically call move constructors

Tags: c++11

I have the following code sample:

```
void MyClass::Register2(std::string name, std::string email)
{
    m_name = std::move(name);
    m_email = std::move(email);
}

void MyClass::Register1(std::string name)
{
     Register2(std::move(name), "invalid_email");
}
```

My questions are:

1. Do I need to use std::move when calling Register2() from Register1()?
2. Do I need to call std::move() inside Register1()?
3. If the answer for question 2. is yes, would be possible to have a dedicated operator instead?

For example:

```
void MyClass::Register2(std::string name, std::string email)
{
    m_name <= name; // perform move
    m_email <= email; // perform move
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to use std::move when calling Register2() from Register1()?

Yes, because `name` is an *lvalue* and you want to turn it into an *rvalue*.

---

> Do I need to call std::move() inside Register1()?

Yes, for the same reason as above.

---

> If the answer for question 2. is yes, would be possible to have a dedicated operator instead?

It would be possible, but I do not think it has been proposed. Also, if it were to be proposed, I do not think it would be accepted as it doesn't bring much value over `std::move`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. No

`std::move` looks something like this

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::remove_reference_t<T>&& move(T&& value) {
    return static_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>&&>(value);
}
```

All it does is it casts the thing you pass as the argument to an rvalue. This step is essential because arguments, even if you pass an rvalue, are always lvalues (because they have names). Lvalues are not moveable, therefore if you don't cast them to an rvalue, move mechanics won't kick in and they will be simply copied.

Operators are functions and there are no exceptions in this case. Special move operator hasn't been proposed and is extremly unlikely to be because it would make the standard longer and more complex (compilers would also be heavily affected) for a feature that saves a couple chars.